# How to perform selector with a nested function?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I have a nested function like this and I want to call `childFunc` when user tap to my button, but it does not work

```
class MyClass {
    func parentFunc() {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(parentFunc().childFunc), for: .touchUpInside)
        func childFunc() {
            print("User tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

It raise error like this:

```
Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'childFunc'
```

Is there any way to perform `childFunc` with `#selector` ?

Edit 1:
I have use closure like this, But I think it's not a nice way because I have to make another function

```
class MyClass {
    myClosure: () -> () = {}
    func parentFunc() {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(runChildFunc), for: .touchUpInside)
        func childFunc() {
            print("User tapped")
        }
        myClosesure = childFunc

    }
    func runChildFunc() {
        myClosure()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead, you can try below code to achieve your goal

```
class MyClass {
    let button = UIButton()

   @objc public func parentFunc(_ sender : UIButton?) 
      {

        func childFunc() {
         print("User tapped")
        }

        if sender != nil && sender.tag == 100{
        childFunc()
        return
        }

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(parentFunc(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = 100
       }
    }
```

In above code, Sender is optional so you can pass nil when you don't want to call child function like `parentFunc(nil)`

Comment: Welcome :) and thanks to StackOverflow community to provide such a great platform.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to perform childFunc with #selector

No. The entire idea makes no sense. Keep in mind that the nested (inner) func *does not really exist*. It only *comes* into existence, momentarily, *when the outer func runs*. The running of the outer func *brings* the inner func into existence at the moment the definition is encountered, effectively storing it in a local variable, so that it is callable from subsequent code in scope *inside* the func. And like any local variable, when the outer func code ends, the inner func goes back out of existence. Also, because it is a local variable inside the func, it is scoped in such a way that it couldn't be called into from outside, even if such a notion made sense — just as a local variable inside a func cannot be seen from outside the func, even if *that* notion made sense.

The selector must point to a *method* of a class instance (where the class derives from NSObject). This is a Cocoa Objective-C architecture; you have to obey Objective-C rules.

Comment: What you'd really like to do, perhaps, is hand the button a closure instead of using the target–action architecture. That's a great idea, and you can find lots of discussion on Stack Overflow about how to configure such a thing (such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919472/adding-a-closure-as-target-to-a-uibutton), but it is not how the target–action architecture works.

Comment: then Nguyen should use the closure pattern from your link. but then he has to use a different syntax