# Protocol extension with button and selector

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, protocols, selector

I have some protocol:

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol { }
```

that I extend for `UIViewController` instances. In this extension I want to create and add a button, whose selector is also defined in the protocol:

```
extension SomeProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

    func addSomeButton() {
        let someButton = UIButton()
        someButton.addTarget(self, #selector(someButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(someButton)
    }

    @objc func someButtonPressed() {
    }

}
```

However, I get the error **@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes** at the definition of `someButtonPressed`.

Is there any way to achieve this using protocols?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: why not `extension UIViewController` ?? tried `@objc protocol`

Comment: @Sh_Khan Hi. It was an `@objc` protocol (fixed the typo now). I'm trying to move to Swift protocols for doing things like this, so that I don't have a very length `UIViewController` with lots of extensions. Do you know of a way to do this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is adding a closure sleeve to the `UIButton` instead of a target action as in shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41438789/5058116 and copied below for convenience.

```
typealias Closure = () -> ()

///
class ClosureSleeve {
    let closure: Closure
    init(_ closure: @escaping Closure) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    @objc func invoke () {
        closure()
    }
}

extension UIControl {
    func addAction(for controlEvents: UIControl.Event = .touchUpInside, _ closure: @escaping Closure) {
        let sleeve = ClosureSleeve(closure)
        addTarget(sleeve, action: #selector(ClosureSleeve.invoke), for: controlEvents)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, String(format: "[%d]", arc4random()), sleeve, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

Then simply replace:

```
someButton.addTarget(self, #selector(someButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

with:

```
someButton.addAction { [weak self] in
        self?.someButtonPressed()
    }
```

and hey presto.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply a `Selector` requirement in the protocol. This is because you can only apply the `@objc` attribute to an `NSObject`. The only reason to mark a protocol `@objc` is for optional methods.

```swift
@objc protocol SomeProtocol {
    var action: Selector { get }
}
```

Change the extension to this:

```swift
extension SomeProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func addSomeButton() {
        let someButton = UIButton()
        someButton.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(someButton)
    }
}
```

Now, this works:

```swift
extension UIViewController: SomeProtocol {
    @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
    }
    var action: Selector {
        return #selector(buttonPressed(sender:))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let vc: myViewController: MyViewController!
func doSomething() {
  vc.addSomeButton()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I'd like to keep the implementation of `buttonPressed` *inside* the protocol extension, please. This is to minimise the length of the `UIViewController` so I'm not adding lots of extensions.

Comment: You will not have to. Just define it in `UIViewController` and all the subclasses will get it for free.

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way to include this solely in the protocol?

Comment: No. As I said in my answer, the `@objc` attribute requires `NSObject`. There is no way to guarantee a Swift protocol only is for `NSObject`s. :(

Comment: @ImportAccelerate Yes you can with the newest toolchain. However I tried it out and thats not working. objc attributes are just not allowed in protocol extensions.

Comment: I know that. What is your confusion?

Comment: @j-doe is there another way to do this perhaps without extending `UIViewControllers`?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate I did read that bit, but thanks for further explaining.

Comment: There is no other way

Comment: @Import-Accelerate See my answer if you're interested.

Comment: Interesting solution but feels kinda of hacky. I like pure Swift.