# Trailing closures with named parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on my own alert implementation and for that I created `AlertViewController`.

My `AlertViewController` contains actions (buttons) and textFields. To add actions I use the following method:

```swift
func addAction(title: String, handler: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
    let button = UIButton()

    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.label, for: .normal)
    if let handler = handler {
        button.addAction(handler)
    }

    actionsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    return self
}
```

I use the following extension to be able to add a closure as an action on a UIButton (find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41438789/6948201)):

```swift
@objc class ClosureSleeve: NSObject {
    let closure: () -> Void

    init (_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    @objc func invoke () {
        closure()
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func addAction(for controlEvents: UIControl.Event = .touchUpInside, _ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let sleeve = ClosureSleeve(closure)

        addTarget(sleeve, action: #selector(ClosureSleeve.invoke), for: controlEvents)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "[\(arc4random())]", sleeve, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the textFields from my `AlertViewController` from a call to `addAction` in the following way:

```swift
AlertViewController(title: "Information")
    .addAction(title: "Send") { textFields in
        let text = textFields?.first?.text
    }
    .show(on: self)
```

When I do this I got the following error: `Contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body`

I don't know how to do it at all, I looked on the internet without success because I don't know what to look for.

Edit: I have create a gist with the code of my `AlertViewController` [here](https://gist.github.com/sonnyfournier/8e0fa1eca0d03eeac07e989daf01f55a)

Comment: The title of your question is not accurate. The trailing aspect is not relevant.

Comment: I don't see any text fields in your `AlertViewController`. Are the text fields properties of `AlertViewController`? Can you show how they are created and used?

Comment: @Jessy I know, that's why I specified in my question that I didn't know what to look for on the internet

Comment: @Sweeper I added the code of my `AlertViewController` in a gist at the end of the question

Comment: @R3J3CT3D I know you said that, but it seems that you know what a parameter and trailing closure are, from your code. So it's confusing; it seems like you have an idea of what you're looking for, but then just picked some terminology that's *kind of associated* with the problem, but not really. Confusing!

Comment: @Jessy I have the possibility to edit the title, what title would you suggest?

Comment: I honestly can't tell what you're asking. See if you can whittle it down yourself, and find out!

Answer (score 0):

Capture only what you need. A capture list is different than the signature of your closure, which doesn't use any parameters.

If it's `textFields`:

```swift
alertViewController.addAction(title: "Add") { [textFields = alertViewController.textFields] in
    print(textFields)
}
```

Otherwise:

```swift
alertViewController.addAction(title: "Add") { [unowned alertViewController] in
    print(alertViewController.textFields)
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: `Variable used within its own initial value`

Comment: Why is that? I tried it out and do not. So I think you should simplify your code, demonstrate where the error shows up, and then report back!

Comment: It's because I want to use `addAction` on `AlertViewController` initialisation and not on a instance like `alertViewController`. I have updated the question with the `AlertViewController` code and the code I would like to use.

Comment: There's no way to do it with chaining because you don't have access to the `AlertViewController`.